# Одновременное нажатие на две кнопки

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно реализовать следующее:
есть две кнопки UIButton, при одновременном нажатии на обе должно выполняться некое действие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте повесить этот скрипт на две Ваши кнопки.

У него есть проблемы

1. Не знаю как это скажется на мобильном устройстве, но персоналке можно нажать на кнопку, затем нажать альт-таб и тогда `OnPointerUp` не случится со всеми вытекающими.
2. Не получится повесить этот скрипт на другую пару кнопок.

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class GroupAction : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler  {

    static int count = 0;       

    bool pressed = false;

    void Start() {
        count = 0;  
    } 

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData){
        if (pressed)
            return;
        pressed = true;
        count++;
        if (count < 2)
             return;

        Debug.Log("action");
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData){
        if (!pressed)
            return;
        pressed = false;
        count--;
    }
}
```

Если Вам не нравится иметь дело со статикой и её переинициализацией, можно сделать ссылку на связанную кнопку, но тогда будет тупняк с взаимным указанием ссылок + возможность случайно сломать эту логику не правильно расставив ссылки в инспекторе.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, на Android работает исправно, это необходимо для родительского разрешения перед покупкой

Comment: @GR1995 Отлично что помогло, но осторожнее со статикой